# iOS Confirm UIAlertView in "Are you sure?" Setting App

Tags: ios, settings, alertview

I need a data reset switch my application, I'd like to put it in Settings->Apps->MyAppName section of iOS. Being a destructive action I want iOS to prompt the user for confirmation. Is there a way to display an alertview style confirmation box from within app settings?

Placing the switch and alertview within the app is no problem to me, I just can't figure out how to display an alert from the settings page. Google searches haven't yielded anything so far.

Thanks

Comment: There is no API for the settings.bundle, therefor you can not interact with the user. So there is no way to present or let iOS present a dialog.

Comment: Dang, what a shame. My only work around then might be...to set the switch outside the app, then the app could prompt the user on startup/ or applicationWillEnterForeground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the "delete all data" switch on the settings page of your application wouldn't do anything to the data stored by your app. Only a property within the `NSUserDefaults` would become `YES`. Since it is up to your app to delete all data the next time it becomes active (checking the `NSUserDefaults`), you can display an `UIAlertView` from your app that gets a confirmation from the user.

It is not possible to integrate such a logic right in the settings app.

Answer (score 1):

Simple **NO** is the answer here. You have no possibility to access what happens in the `Settings` App of the iOS device that uses your app. You can only configure *what* should be configured, no logic can be added.